# After update to gradle 2.2 Error:Unable to find method

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I updated my gradle plugin version to `2.2.0` today:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'`

and then got the error:

> Error:Unable to find method 'com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream.computeInt64Size(IJ)I'.

I tried to do the suggested tasks like resyncing and restarting the IDE but nothing helped.

Comment: Usually Build ->Clean Project or File ->Invalidate Caches / Restart helps.

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately

Comment: How did you add the protobuf stuff (jar) to your project? could you add this to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched again and found this link:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215548

I fixed it by increasing the version number of the kotlin gradle plugin to at least 1.0.3

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.3"
```